# why doesn't my file upload script work?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

Do you see what's wrong here? I can't find anything.

this prints:

```
echo $_FILES["new_text_file"]["name"];
```

and this too:

```
echo $_FILES["new_text_file"]["tmp_name"];
```

**php:**
    
";
        echo $_FILES["new_text_file"]["tmp_name"];
            //Uploads the text file to the server

```
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["new_text_file"]["tmp_name"]), $_FILES["new_text_file"]["name"]) 
        {
            //header('Location: ga-dev-exercise-pavan.php');
            echo 'worked';
        }else {
            echo 'did not work';
        }
}
?>
```

**html:**

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="ga-dev-exercise-pavan.php" method="POST">
        Choose a text file you want to upload and search through: 
        <input type='file' name='new_text_file'>

        <input type="hidden" name="submit_yes_file" value="true" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="upload">
    </form>
```

Comment: Move the file to another folder. You're currently leaving it in the tmp folder

Comment: Use method=GET so you can see what's going inside the parameters. It might help you find out where your error is.

Comment: Do:  var_dump($_FILES); to see the complete information inside the variable and be sure that is not a typo on the key names.

Comment: @user1534664 not recommended on production and potentially hard to switch from (can be anticipated)

Comment: @JanDvorak true. I only recommend it for now because he can't find his error, and often it might turn out that the parameters are empty or stuff like that.

Comment: So the issue was the parentheses. I can't believe I missed that. My error reporting is turned off, because if it was turned on, my other site which has a lot of users would experience a ton of errors.

Comment: @Mr.Alien It wasn't uploading the file to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses were off. It should be like this:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["new_text_file"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["new_text_file"]["name"]))
```

Answer (score 2):

you should specify a target path

```
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

**Edit :**
as mentioned in comments , parentheses are misplaced :

**wrong :**

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["new_text_file"]["tmp_name"]), $_FILES["new_text_file"]["name"])

**correct**

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["new_text_file"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["new_text_file"]["name"]))

Comment: thanks RezaSh. The issue was the parentheses. I submitted an answer below. I needed the file to be uploaded into the current directory, so that's why I didn't specify a sub directory.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't automatically allowed to move the uploaded file everywhere. You need to move it somewhere your PHP script has permissions to write.

So e.g.

```
$src = $_FILES["new_text_file"]["tmp_name"];
$dst = './tmp_dir/'.basename($_FILES["new_text_file"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($src, $dst))
{
```

The `basename` protects you against the user specifying malicious file paths (does nothing against duplicate file names), the `tmp_dir` is a directory you can write to.

Using `$src` and `$dst` clears a bit the code, and allowed me to see that you had an extra parenthesis in your sample...

Comment: Thanks Iserni. I figured out the issue below. It was the parentheses.